# Manipulating Streams

Tags: design-patterns, .net-4.0, stream, signal-processing

What's the proper way to do this? Assume I've got a stream of audio data and want to apply some audio filters to it before writing it to disk

What should the interface for the filters look like?

```
Sub Process(InputStream as IO.Stream)
```

or

```
Function Process(InputStream as IO.Stream) as IO.Stream
```

?

I suppose I'm a little unclear on how streams should be passed between classes and methods - Do I need to read the entire stream in a method, process it and then write to a new stream which is returned?

What about streams without a fixed length? I don't want to try and read a potentially infinite stream into memory - I want each filter to process a chunk and pass it on to the next filter.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Streams should be passed like anything else. What do you think is special about them?

Comment: Well, I need processing to be continuous - eg Sample 1 arrives, gets processed by say `VolumeUp`, then `PitchShift`, etc... before being written to disk. Whilst sample 1 is being Pitch shifted, sample 2 has arrived and needs to be run through `VolumeUp` etc... Ie it's not discrete data I'm passing around, I need to wire up my classes as processors which I assume should either run in parallel or quick succession...

Comment: So this has nothing to do with how to pass a stream, but rather how tot create a set of "processors" for sequentially processing a stream of data. Do you even have a way to split the stream into samples?

Comment: @John For that matter, assume I've got a method which generates a sine wave and writes it to a stream (as a dummy data source). How can I get the stream out from the `GenerateSineWave()`? If I do a return at the end, I'll have to have stopped generating to exit the function and return a pointer to the stream - Or do I create the stream in the parent, pass it `ByRef` to the generator on a second thread?

Comment: @John, sorry didn't see your response - The problem I can't get my head around is that streams aren't static blocks of memory (ok, they are but they're constantly changing) so how do I stream output from a method and still allow processing to happen inside the method. Apologies if my question is unclear but I'm facing unknown unknowns.

Comment: You're thinking too far ahead, I think. I've never written signal processing code, but it seems that by writing the sine wave to a stream, you're losing the fact that it's a sine wave, just turning it into a sequence of bytes. I don't believe that a Stream is a proper paradigm here.

Comment: @John Also, why doesn't this qualify as a design pattern issue? Surely there must be a pattern for this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3158/discussion-between-basiclife-and-john-saunders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, I think of extending the functionality of Streams using the Decorator Pattern.  In this case, one stream wraps the original and manipulates the data before passing it to the original stream's method. Check out [this article from MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163741.aspx) on creating an `InterceptorStream` that provides additional functionality to the wrapped `Stream`.

Comment: That article explains exactly what I needed to know - Thank you, perfect answer.